# How to trigger open console (F12) event using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, triggers, console

I would like to add a button to my webpage, and when this button clicked, the console will open like what happens when the user click (F12) key on keyboard.

this is my try:

```js
document.querySelector('#openConsole').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('build', true, true);
    event.keyCode = 123; // F12 key code
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<button id="openConsole">open console</button>
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. There's such a thing known as security. JS can't interact with a users computer and / or browser.

Answer (score 2):

Dev tools can't be opened programmatically as it would lead to insecurity.
Opening this would allow control which then could be exploited by injecting data for example.